# Query to get the count of data for particular customer with all other data from table

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

My table structure is as follows:

```
group_id  | cust_id | ticket_num
 ------------------------------
    60    |   12    |   1
    60    |   12    |   2
    60    |   12    |   3
    60    |   12    |   4
    60    |   30    |   5
    60    |   30    |   6
    60    |   31    |   7
    60    |   31    |   8
    65    |   02    |   1
```

I want to fetch all the data for `group_id=60` and find the count of `ticket_num` for each customer in that group. My output should be like this:

```
cust_id  | ticket_count | ticket_num
 ------------------------------
    12    |      4      |   1
    12    |             |   2
    12    |             |   3
    12    |             |   4
    30    |      2      |   5
    30    |             |   6
    31    |      2      |   7
    31    |             |   8
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT gd.cust_id, Count(gd.cust_id),gd.ticket_num 
FROM Group_details gd 
WHERE gd.group_id = 65 
GROUP BY gd.cust_id;
```

But this query is not working.

Comment: . . Please tag the question with the database you ware using.  Also explain what "not working" means.  If there is an error message, share it.

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate and subquery

```
   select t2.*,t1.ticket_num from Group_details t1
   inner join
   ( 
   SELECT gd.cust_id, Count(gd.ticket_num) as ticket_count 
   FROM Group_details gd where gd.group_id = 60 
   GROUP BY gd.cust_id 
   ) t2 on t1.cust_id=t2.cust_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd718b/1

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want the ANSI/ISO standard `row_number()` functions and `count()` as a window function:

```
select gd.cust_id, count(*) over (partition by gd.cust_id) as num_tickets,
       row_number() over (order by gd.cust_id) as ticket_seqnum
from group_details gd
where gd.group_id = 60;
```

Comment: getting this error...#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by gd.cust_id) as num_tickets, row_number() over (order by gd' at line 1